# How to make Slider with one Big image in center and has only three slides with auto slide feature

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

How can i make this slider with

- 3 different Images on it
- 3 Different text on it
- Button which will open Modal Dialog like Bootstrap and each Slide's Button will show different text on modal.
- Slide must be auto sliding

Please see this screenshot of
[Slider Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoqdH.png)

```js
$(".center").slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    autoplay: true,
    speed: 300,
    dots: true,
    arrows: true
  });
```

```css
html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .slider {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 100px auto;
    }

    .slick-slide {
      margin: 0px 20px;
    }

    .slick-slide img {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
      color: black;
    }


    .slick-slide {
      transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
      opacity: .2;
    }
    
    .slick-active {
      opacity: .5;
    }

    .slick-current {
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.0/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.0/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.0/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="slider-inner">
    <section class="center slider">
       <div>
           <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
       </div>
       <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
       </div>
        <div>
           <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
       </div>
   </section>
</div>
```

Note: I am using Bootstrap 4.5 in my Project.

Please help, as i am newbie in this field and got this School Project.

Comment: Look into [slick slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). It's a jQuery slider and has these features. Look at the documentation and examples. You'll do great.

Comment: No, my friend. It will work on 3 as well. You just have to adjust the settings.

Comment: Alright great, that's a lot more to work with. Currently your script does not run as Slick Slider uses jQuery. Be sure to include jQuery version 1.7 (or above) before the script `slick.min.js`. Then your slider will run. Sidenote: I recommended slick slider because you said you used bootstrap, which also uses jQuery.

Comment: Now i added newest version of jquery in the post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did it!

Now all you have to change is the `slidesToShow` property in the settings. Although you see 3 slides in your image, there is actually only 1 active slide.

That because `centerMode` is `true` and the entire slider will offset to the center, showing a hint of the previous and next slide.

Examine the example below.

```js
$(".center").slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  speed: 300,
  dots: true,
  arrow: true
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  color: black;
}

.slick-slide {
  transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
  transform: translate3d(20%, 0, 0) scale(0.8);
  opacity: .2;
}

.slick-active {
  opacity: .5;
}

.slick-current {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.slick-current ~ .slick-slide {
  transform: translate3d(-20%, 0, 0) scale(0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.0/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.0/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.0/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="slider-inner">
  <section class="center slider">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, but can you make this one as i mentioned in the post?

I tried to stretch this but it's breaking if i try changing it..

Comment: Do you mean like in the image? What do you mean with stretching?